# How to interactively (e.g. using the terminal) intervene a for loop

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm training my DQN and it often happens that I want to change a setting in the middle of the training. I know there is the option to terminate the running code via the terminal with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> but I'd like to intervene only after the currently running epoch has finished. Is there a way to implement that. (I'm using VS-Code)

Comment: How about to use a timed input (after certain amount of time skip input), you can read more and see example [https://www.semicolonworld.com/question/44145/python-3-timed-input](https://www.semicolonworld.com/question/44145/python-3-timed-input)

Answer (score 0):

You could insert a `input()` after every epoch and use this.. But that means that you have to sit in front of the computer the whole execution time to make the program execute without long pauses

Comment: I thought of that but I can't afford to sit there and give an input after every epoch. Most of the time I train it over night, while I'm sleeping.